# Screen freezes then recovers after several minutes

Tags: 22.04, freeze

I'm experiencing occasional screen freezing where the screen is still visible but nothing updates or responds to input.

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Dell XPS 8910
- Intel i7-6700
- 32 GB RAM
- SSD for system disk
- Kernel 5.15.0-41
- NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti
- Using X.Org X server driver

Installed 2 weeks ago.
Have been running Ubuntu on it for several years without issue.

Sometimes the mouse still moves, sometimes not.

I'm pretty sure the freeze was after 16:00.

Logs

```
16:57:26 cat: [2022-07-27 16:57:26.896] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:56:57 gnome-shell: Could not create transient scope for PID 0: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitExists: Unit app-gnome-org.gnome.Logs-0.scope already exists.
16:56:56 cat: [2022-07-27 16:56:56.875] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:56:56 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=386852] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Logs'
16:56:53 cat: [2022-07-27 16:56:53.872] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:55:54 Xorg: (EE) event4  - Razer Razer Abyssus Essential: WARNING: log rate limit exceeded (5 msgs per 60min). Discarding future messages.
16:55:53 cat: [2022-07-27 16:55:53.831] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:55:50 Xorg: (EE) event4  - Razer Razer Abyssus Essential: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 21ms, your system is too slow
16:55:50 cat: [2022-07-27 16:55:50.828] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:54:31 Xorg: (EE) event4  - Razer Razer Abyssus Essential: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 24ms, your system is too slow
16:54:29 cat: [2022-07-27 16:54:29.752] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:53:33 Xorg: (EE) event9  - Kinesis Advantage2 Keyboard: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 29ms, your system is too slow
16:53:32 cat: [2022-07-27 16:53:32.706] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:53:30 Xorg: (EE) event4  - Razer Razer Abyssus Essential: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 24ms, your system is too slow
16:53:29 cat: [2022-07-27 16:53:29.704] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:52:05 Xorg: (EE) event4  - Razer Razer Abyssus Essential: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 21ms, your system is too slow
16:52:05 cat: [2022-07-27 16:52:05.633] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:46:36 gnome-shell: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55c0ab01b4a0] is on because it needs an allocation.
16:46:35 cat: [2022-07-27 16:46:35.383] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:46:12 Xorg: (EE) event9  - Kinesis Advantage2 Keyboard: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 22ms, your system is too slow
16:46:11 cat: [2022-07-27 16:46:11.364] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:43:22 NetworkManager: <info>  [1658965402.8198] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=2600:1700:4540:c290::17
16:43:20 cat: [2022-07-27 16:43:20.223] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:42:13 gnome-shell: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55c0ab551be0] is on because it needs an allocation.
16:42:11 cat: [2022-07-27 16:42:11.174] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:42:03 systemd: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
16:42:02 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=386852] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Logs'
16:42:02 cat: [2022-07-27 16:42:02.165] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:42:01 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=386852] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Characters.BackgroundService'
16:41:59 cat: [2022-07-27 16:41:59.164] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:41:35 gnome-shell: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55c0ab01b820] is on because it needs an allocation.
16:41:35 cat: [2022-07-27 16:41:35.148] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:41:23 systemd: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
16:41:23 cat: [2022-07-27 16:41:23.140] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:41:10 gnome-shell: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55c0ab01b820] is on because it needs an allocation.
16:41:08 cat: [2022-07-27 16:41:08.129] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:40:55 gnome-shell: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.2
16:40:55 okular-bin: Skipped method "setDefaultShortcuts" : Pointers are not supported: QAction*
16:40:55 gnome-shell: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
16:40:55 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=386852] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ArchiveManager1'
16:40:55 gnome-shell: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
16:40:55 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=386852] Activating service name='org.gnome.ArchiveManager1' requested by ':1.1767' (uid=1000 pid=574654 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
16:40:55 gnome-shell: unable to update icon for livepatch
16:40:55 NetworkManager: <info>  [1658965255.0368] agent-manager: agent[c7357a1b105d8865,:1.3081/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
16:40:54 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
16:40:53 gnome-shell: JS ERROR: Failed to initialize fprintd service: Gio.IOErrorEnum: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:114:23

16:40:53 systemd: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
16:40:53 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
16:40:53 systemd: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
16:40:53 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.3081' (uid=1000 pid=573047 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
16:40:53 cat: [2022-07-27 16:40:53.123] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:30:48 systemd: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
16:30:48 anacron: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
16:30:48 systemd: Started Run anacron jobs.
16:30:46 cat: [2022-07-27 16:30:46.708] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:30:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
16:30:01 kernel: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
16:30:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
16:30:01 cat: [2022-07-27 16:30:01.680] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:20:24 gnome-shell: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55c0ab01aa20] is on because it needs an allocation.
16:20:22 cat: [2022-07-27 16:20:22.331] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:19:57 systemd: Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
16:19:57 nautilus: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
16:19:55 cat: [2022-07-27 16:19:55.316] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:19:43 gnome-shell: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55c0ab01b820] is on because it needs an allocation.
16:19:40 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=386852] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Characters.BackgroundService'
16:19:40 cat: [2022-07-27 16:19:40.307] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:17:26 systemd: Started VTE child process 573442 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 425057.
16:17:25 cat: [2022-07-27 16:17:25.188] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
16:17:01 cat: [2022-07-27 16:17:01.171] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:16:58 systemd: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.
16:16:58 geoclue: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
16:16:58 cat: [2022-07-27 16:16:58.167] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:16:04 gnome-shell: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.2
16:16:04 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=386852] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ArchiveManager1'
16:16:04 gnome-shell: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x55c0ab550a60] is on because it needs an allocation.
16:16:04 cat: [2022-07-27 16:16:04.120] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:16:03 gnome-shell: Registering session with GDM
16:16:02 okular-bin: Skipped method "setDefaultShortcuts" : Pointers are not supported: QAction*
16:16:02 gnome-shell: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
16:16:02 Xorg: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
16:16:01 cat: [2022-07-27 16:16:01.116] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:16:00 Xorg: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
16:16:00 gnome-shell: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
16:16:00 NetworkManager: <info>  [1658963760.0155] agent-manager: agent[97102cec8f728c7a,:1.3081/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
16:15:59 gsd-media-keys: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-repeat
16:15:59 systemd: Started GNOME Shell on X11.
16:15:59 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=386852] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.Notifications'
16:15:58 systemd: app-gnome-org.gnome.Software-0.scope: Consumed 39min 49.658s CPU time.
16:15:58 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
16:15:58 gnome-shell: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
16:15:58 polkitd: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:372 (system bus name :1.3081 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
16:15:58 systemd: Starting Location Lookup Service...
16:15:58 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.3081' (uid=1000 pid=573047 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
16:15:58 gnome-shell: Will monitor session 372
16:15:58 gsd-media-keys: Failed to grab accelerators: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Object does not exist at path “/org/gnome/Shell”
16:15:58 cat: [2022-07-27 16:15:58.115] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:15:57 Xorg: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
16:15:57 gnome-shell: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 42.2) as a X11 window and compositing manager
16:15:57 systemd: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
16:15:57 kernel: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic
16:15:57 systemd: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Consumed 5.064s CPU time.
16:15:57 polkitd: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:372 (system bus name :1.2177, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
16:15:57 systemd: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
16:15:57 whoopsie: [16:15:57] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
16:15:57 systemd: Started crash report submission.
16:15:55 cat: [2022-07-27 16:15:55.112] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:15:46 systemd: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
16:15:46 whoopsie: [16:15:46] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
16:15:46 systemd: Started crash report submission.
16:15:46 NetworkManager: <info>  [1658963746.4710] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=2600:1700:4540:c290::17
16:15:46 cat: [2022-07-27 16:15:46.107] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:15:45 gnome-shell: == Stack trace for context 0x5577d0550190 ==
16:15:43 cat: [2022-07-27 16:15:43.104] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
16:13:40 gnome-shell: nouveau:  0x1000f010
16:13:40 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[386994]: channel 6 killed!
16:13:40 cat: [2022-07-27 16:13:40.016] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices

15:52:36 Xorg: (EE) event4  - Razer Razer Abyssus Essential: WARNING: log rate limit exceeded (5 msgs per 60min). Discarding future messages.
15:52:36 cat: [2022-07-27 15:52:36.108] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:52:26 Xorg: (EE) event4  - Razer Razer Abyssus Essential: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 42ms, your system is too slow
15:52:24 cat: [2022-07-27 15:52:24.099] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:52:22 Xorg: (EE) event4  - Razer Razer Abyssus Essential: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 22ms, your system is too slow
15:52:21 cat: [2022-07-27 15:52:21.096] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:52:15 Xorg: (EE) event4  - Razer Razer Abyssus Essential: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 26ms, your system is too slow
15:52:15 cat: [2022-07-27 15:52:15.091] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:51:58 Xorg: (EE) event4  - Razer Razer Abyssus Essential: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 26ms, your system is too slow
15:51:57 cat: [2022-07-27 15:51:57.078] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:49:16 Xorg: (EE) event9  - Kinesis Advantage2 Keyboard: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 26ms, your system is too slow
15:49:14 cat: [2022-07-27 15:49:14.940] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:48:00 systemd: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
15:47:59 cat: [2022-07-27 15:47:59.883] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:47:41 okular-bin: Skipped method "setDefaultShortcuts" : Pointers are not supported: QAction*
15:47:41 gnome-shell: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.2
15:47:41 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=386852] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ArchiveManager1'
15:47:40 gnome-shell: unable to update icon for livepatch
15:47:40 NetworkManager: <info>  [1658962060.9512] agent-manager: agent[63d0fea55783f371,:1.2177/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
15:47:40 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
15:47:38 cat: [2022-07-27 15:47:38.867] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:47:30 gnome-shell: JS ERROR: Failed to initialize fprintd service: Gio.IOErrorEnum: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:114:23

15:47:30 systemd: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
15:47:30 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
15:47:30 kernel: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic
15:47:30 systemd: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
15:47:30 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.2177' (uid=1000 pid=387432 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
15:47:30 gnome-shell: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
15:47:30 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
15:47:29 cat: [2022-07-27 15:47:29.859] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:45:59 systemd: Started app-flatpak-com.brave.Browser-570785.scope.
15:45:56 cat: [2022-07-27 15:45:56.752] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:45:46 NetworkManager: <info>  [1658961946.4702] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=2600:1700:4540:c290::17
15:45:44 cat: [2022-07-27 15:45:44.736] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:45:34 systemd: Started app-flatpak-com.google.Chrome-570736.scope.
15:45:32 cat: [2022-07-27 15:45:32.722] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:32:17 kernel: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
15:32:17 kernel: Anacron 2.3 started on 2022-07-27
15:32:17 systemd: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
15:32:16 cat: [2022-07-27 15:32:16.826] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:30:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
15:30:01 kernel: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
15:30:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
15:30:01 cat: [2022-07-27 15:30:01.678] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:17:10 NetworkManager: <info>  [1658960230.0602] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=2600:1700:4540:c290::17
15:17:09 cat: [2022-07-27 15:17:09.825] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
15:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
15:17:01 kernel: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
15:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
15:17:00 cat: [2022-07-27 15:17:00.816] [124] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
```

**Adding additional logs from this morening.**
This morning screens were blank but on. Should have been asleep. Computer appeared unresponsive and had to do a hard shutdown

```
 7:04:23 AM kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
 7:04:23 AM gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 7:04:23 AM gnome-session-b: GLib-CRITICAL: g_hash_table_foreach_remove_or_steal: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
 7:04:18 AM systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
 7:04:16 AM gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
 7:04:11 AM systemd: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
 7:04:10 AM gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
 7:04:07 AM thermald: Thermal DTS or hwmon: No Zones present Need to configure manually
 7:04:07 AM kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
 7:04:07 AM kernel: 
 7:04:07 AM kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
 7:04:06 AM kernel: uvcvideo 1-13:1.1: Failed to set UVC probe control : -32 (exp. 26).
 7:04:06 AM kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
 7:04:06 AM kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
 7:04:06 AM kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
 7:04:06 AM kernel: DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x000000007d800000-0x000000007fffffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
```

I did find there was a firmware update for my graphics card and performed the update.

I also see 2 firmware bugs in the above logs so will be looking into those.

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing the NVIDIA Drivers:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver-515 libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386

Comment: I did that. Hard to tell if it cures freezing as it is a once a week kind of thing. However with the NVIDIA drivers I get another problem, when the screens go blank and the monitors sleep I can't get the screens back to life. Stuck with a black screens. Have to do a hard shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get a solution to this but did find a workaround. My video card has 3 outputs, 2 DVI & 1 mini-HDMI. I only have a problem when using the mini-HDMI. I got around this by using the 2 DVI + the HDMI from the motherboard.

The issue sounds similar to this: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nv-uefi-update-x64/

However, performing the firmware update didn't change anything. I read, but sorry, lost the reference to, something that discussed that my BIOS needed an update in order to work with the firmware update but it is a DELL BIOS and they have no plans to address the issue.

Hope that is useful to someone else :)